# How does cdt build environment populate the path?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Does anybody know how Eclipse CDT populate the path variable when the origin is "BUILD SYSTEM"?  I thought through the global environment, but my system path is set to visual studio 2010 and somehow cdt find visual studio 2012 and will not compile for 2010.

path shown by process explorer (c:\apps\MVS10)
[image]

path detected by cdt (c:\apps\MVS11): 
[image]

I'm using eclipse Luna 20140612-0600 + CDT 8.4.0.201406111759

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling, I found this bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357980.

So CDT is hardcoded to detect Visual Studio through the registry and it uses the latest that it found and there's is no way (to my knowledge) in Eclipse to change it to a different version without hardcoding the path to the project; which I can't do because I'm not the only person working on the project.

WinEnvironmentVariableSupplier.java

```
private static String getVCDir() {
    WindowsRegistry reg = WindowsRegistry.getRegistry();
    String vcDir = getSoftwareKey(reg, "Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\SxS\\VC7", "11.0");
    if (vcDir != null)
        return vcDir;
    vcDir = getSoftwareKey(reg, "Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\SxS\\VC7", "10.0");
    if (vcDir != null)
        return vcDir;
    return getSoftwareKey(reg, "Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\SxS\\VC7", "9.0");
}
```

My workaround for this problem is to redefine the wrong variables to Eclipse's variables; just make sure to call vcvarsall.bat before launching Eclipse:

- INCLUDE = ${INCLUDE}
- LIB = ${LIB}
- PATH = ${PATH}

[image]